# Why serilog is not working if you copy the bin/Debug files to other directory or machine?

Tags: c#, serilog

I have created a console application that logs every event in an application using serilog library. The application loggings is working nicely in running mode on my machine. But when I copied the bin/Debug files to another machine the loggings are not working.

Comment: First of all, "bin/Debug" is not meant for deployment. And then, this could have several reasons. Please share serilog config and maybe the contents (file listing) of your "bin/Debug" Folder.

Comment: Is the computer on? if so, I have no idea, you will have to do some basic debugging. The problem could be 1 of 3534534 possible reasons.

Comment: Did you enable Serilog's internal logging? `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);`

Comment: @Fildor yeah it is not for deployment but this is only a console application.

Comment: @TheGeneral yes the computer is on

Comment: @Fildor what is the purpose of Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg)); Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);? If I use the WriteTo.File()?

Comment: The purpose is to Debug Serilog itself. If there is any issue with the configuration for example, this is where you can find out. After you fixed it, you remove the internal logging again.

Comment: Do you configure in code or by appsettings? Please add the configuration to your question by [edit]ing it. There are 2 close votes already. The question is lacking crucial information. If you are interested in a useful answer, please add some information.